How use LIKE in a in a free text fields separated by | to compare it to a spacific column
i want to compare a column with a specific textfield which is separated by | using like statement
| Column A      | 
| --------      | 
| bobo   vera   | 
|               |


i used this code to get the result
=IIf(lookup(Fields!IDa1.value,Fields!ID.value,Fields!givenName.value,"Brother_Sister")<>"",
(Join(lookupSet(CStr(Fields!FamilyID.Value), Fields!BrotherGrpID.value,

    CStr(Fields!givenName.value),

"Brother_Sister"),"|")),"")

I got this result
Bobo Vera|Bobo Vera|Bob Veras|Bobos Veras| Bob, Verra
Then I want to compare the result  using Like or contains knowing that Bobo Vera is the ID a1 which need to be compare to the all the row ensuring that all the row must be the same id not same writte "Not same" if  Same  writte "Succes"
i need to compare this colum with text fiel which i obtain from LookupSte fuction which is like:
bobo bera|guelord|raissa kenza|bobo vera|Bobos Veras|...|...|
i want to know if column A is  like all different elements separated by |
note that the number and length of element separated by | is not known.
column1 like ""+"|"+"@text+"+"|"+""

if this elates to your previous question, then edit that question as it already has much more context. If you think this is an entirely new question,. then show sample data with expected output based on that sample data.

Dear @AlanSchofield, thanks you so very much for your feedback, i have updated my question, and hope i can support
